# Convert Int Value To Bit Value For Grid Display

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, data-conversion

I am running a sql stored procedure and returning the results to a grid.  I want to convert an int column to bit so that it will display in my grid as check boxes as opposed to a 1 or 0 value.

I have seen examples of convert to a bit array, but can't find a way to convert to bit, and my intellisense does not provide an option of `Convert.ToBit`

EDIT --- (thanks @Ekad)
Looks like it would actually be `Convert.ToBoolean` --- now how would I create the field to be a checkbox, and how do I assign a checked/unchecked value?

Comment: There's no bit type in C#, however if you want to display as checkboxes, boolean is the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Directly convert in stored procedure from int column to bit

```
CONVERT(bit,ColumnValue)
```

or

can Use If Else In C# code

Answer (score 1):

to expand on ekad's answer: what you would typically do, if you must start from an integer, is use a calculated property

```
public int AnInteger { get; set; }
    public bool IntAsBoolean
    {
        get
        {
            return AnInteger > 0;
        }
    }
```